# Trying to calculate the end of the next day in node.js

Tags: node.js, date, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the end of the next day for any given date as an expiry date.

So if the input is eg 10/26/2013 16:36:46 then I'd like to get 10/27/2013 23:59:59 and 7/31/2013 16:36:46 would give me 8/1/2013 23:59:59

It gets obviously difficult with leap years and when the next day is a new month. So I tried to use the dateParse function which gives me a number that I can easily add 86400000 (full day in milliseconds) and then I want to use basically the reverse of dateParse (turn a number into a date object) so that I can then take out the date component and replace the time component with 23:59:59

Here's my code which doesn't work - setTime doesn't seem to be the right function and makes my next_day variable "undefined"

```
    var next_day = call_start.dateParse + 86400000; // adding a full day to it
    next_day = next_day.setTime;
    var day = next_day.getDate;
    day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
    var month = next_day.getMonth + 1;
    month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
    var year = next_day.getFullYear;
    var hour = 23;
    var min = 59;
    var sec = 59;
    var expiry = year + ":" + month + ":" + day + ":" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    console.log ('Streak expires at: ' + expiry);
```

Comment: I see a lot of unnecessary complication to your code. You can try out moment.js, it will do the hard work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `set*` functions to modify the date:

```
var date = new Date('7/31/2013 16:36:46');

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
date.setHours(23);
date.setMinutes(59);
date.setSeconds(59);

console.log(date);
// Thu Aug 01 2013 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: Thanks Gergo, your code does exactly what I was looking for. I just had to assign my date in a string format with the "new Date" and all was fine, like: date = new Date(call_start);